# "exact" cause blank page production mode

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS world, and I'm having a trouble with the production.

So, I'm learning about Router because I'm doing a sort of website with a login.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import IndexPage from './IndexPage/IndexPage';
import HomePage from './HomePage/HomePage';
import { Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import AuthService from './services/AuthService';
import History from './services/History';

const auth = new AuthService();

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      auth.loggedIn() === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/',
            state: { from: props.location }
          }} />
    )} />
  )

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={History}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={IndexPage}/>
            <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={HomePage}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

This is my index.js file, as you can see I've

```
<Route exact path="/" component={IndexPage}/>
```

This line creates the problem. As you can see I'm using exact as param, if I don't use it I got "CANNOT GET /pagename" (for the other components). Now, if I build the website with this "exact" in the line, I've a blank page, else if I build without the exact it "works", but when I log-in I've the homepage behind the login form (I see both in the same page).

Someone could help me? I think that the webpack and the package are correct..

Thank you!

***UPDATE, I SOLVED!***

As Hassan said, I tried to change my route in this way (removing also the exact param):

```
<PrivateRoute path="/home" component={HomePage}/>
<Route path="/" component={IndexPage}/>
```

It worked :D!
Hope this is helpfull!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code flow from

```
<Route exact path="/" component={IndexPage}/>
<PrivateRoute path="/home" component={HomePage}/>
```

To

```
<PrivateRoute path="/home" component={HomePage}/>
<Route path="/" exact component={IndexPage}/>
```

I had a problem like this. Hope this works for you too.
Let me know how it goes